# scipy.optimize minimize inconsistent results

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am getting some very weird results when running the minimize function from scipy optimize.

Here is the code

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def objective(x):
    return - (0.05 * x[0] ** 0.64 + 0.4 * x[1] ** 0.36)

def constraint(x):
    return x[0] + x[1] - 5000

cons = [{'type':'eq', 'fun': constraint}]
```

when running

```
minimize(objective, [2500.0, 2500.0], method='SLSQP',  constraints=cons)
```

i get allocation `2500` for each element of x. 
with `fun: -14.164036415985395`

With a quick check, this allocation `[3800, 1200]` gives `-14.9`

It is highly sensitive to the initial conditions also .

Any thoughts as to what i am doing wrong

the two functions [plotted](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.05%20*%20x%5E0.64%20and%200.40%20*%20x%5E0.36%20from%200%20to%205000)

**UPDATE**
It actually returns the initial conditions.

If i try this though

```
def objective(x):
    return - (x[0] ** 0.64 + x[1] ** 0.36)

def constraint(x):
    return x[0] + x[1] - 5000.0

cons = [{'type':'eq', 'fun': constraint}]

minimize(objective, [2500, 2500], method='SLSQP', constraints=cons)
```

returned results seem to be just fine (i have changed the objective function)

Comment: FYI: Before you look at the parameters returned (i.e. `result.x`), you should first check `result.success`.  Is that value True or False?

Comment: @warren-weckesser thanks for the comment. Both have success = True

Comment: With a grain of salt: while strange at first (assuming the solver will find a local-optimum, which it should) this looks like it's not a convex minimization problem (indefinite hessian) and therefore the guarantees of this solver are not enough to provide a global optimum. For tiny problems like this, global solvers like *couenne* should work. (and two new tags for one question; not sure if that helps)

Comment: If I change the method to `method='trust-constr'`, the result is `[3901.68798782, 1098.31201218]`, which agrees with what I see in a plot of the objective function.  I haven't looked into the details of scipy's minimizers. @sascha's comment might explain the problem--the behavior might be the result of applying the SLSQP algorithm to a problem for which it is not designed. If possible, though, it would be nice if the algorithm could detect that something went wrong and raise an exception.  Could you report this example in an issue at https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser thanks again for looking into it.I haven't looked in t the `method='trust-constr` but when running that i get `Unsupported jac definition.` i will report the issue, sure

Comment: i have version 1.1, It should be fixed when i update

Comment: version 1.2.1 now i get this `array must not contain infs or NaNs` for `method='trust-constr'` for the second example.

Comment: I also used 1.2.1.  I didn't try the second example.  With the first example, I forgot that I had changed the initial guess to [3000, 2000], so it was bit closer to the minimum.  That call finished with no errors or warnings.  If I use [2500, 2500] for the initial guess, I get a warning: `[...]/_hessian_update_strategy.py:187: UserWarning: delta_grad == 0.0. Check if the approximated function is linear. If the function is linear better results can be obtained by defining the Hessian as zero instead of using quasi-Newton approximations.` but the answer is still correct.

Comment: Apparently for `method=trust-constr` there needs to exist an interior solution.
i.e. with just the simple `def objective(x):
    return - (x[0] ** 2 + x[1])` i get an error 
thanks @WarrenWeckesser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has a few upvotes, so I thought it deserves an answer.

> Any thoughts as to what i am doing wrong

Nothing, really. This is just an issue with problem scaling and the default tolerances. An important default termination tolerance of `method='slsqp'` is `1e-6` ([`_minimize_slsqp`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/4edfcaa3ce8a387450b6efce968572def71be089/scipy/optimize/_slsqp_py.py#L218)). By setting that to `1e-7`:

```py
minimize(objective, [2500.0, 2500.0], method='SLSQP', constraints=cons, tol=1e-7)
```

You get the solution you're expecting:

```
 message: Optimization terminated successfully
 success: True
  status: 0
     fun: -14.913839470893286
       x: [ 3.901e+03  1.099e+03]
     nit: 15
     jac: [-1.630e-03 -1.630e-03]
    nfev: 45
    njev: 15
```

Notice that at termination, `x` is on the order of `1e3` and `jac` is on the order of `1e-3`. While the details are more complicated (it probably also has something to do with relationship between the scales of the constraint Jacobian and the gradient), I don't think the 6 orders of magnitude scale difference is a coincidence. If we rescale your problem by making a variable substitution `x = x * scale` in the objective and constraints:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

scale = 1.5  # it doesn't take much

def objective(x):
    x = x*scale
    return - (0.05 * x[0] ** 0.64 + 0.4 * x[1] ** 0.36)

def constraint(x):
    x = x*scale
    return x[0] + x[1] - 5000

cons = [{'type':'eq', 'fun': constraint}]

x0 = np.asarray([2500.0, 2500.0])
minimize(objective, x0/scale, method='SLSQP', constraints=cons)
```

Then we don't change the initial values of the objective or constraint, yet the solver continues on and eventually converges to the expected answer, even without changing the termination tolerance.

You'll find that if you change `scale` to 10, you bring the final `x` and `jac` two orders of magnitude closer together, and you can increase `tol` to `1e-5` and still converge to the desired solution, but with `tol=1e-4` it doesn't.  More generally, if you set `tol = 1e-7 * scale**2`, it converges to the desired solution, but with `tol = 1e-6 * scale**2`, it doesn't (for `scale` within a few orders of magnitude of `1`).

So it looks like your problem in the original "units" is just poorly scaled in the sense that the gradient is very small with respect to the decision variables (or again, the constraint Jacobian might matter, too). Bringing these scales a little closer together gives the solver the nudge it needs to find a better solution.